# ERC1155 token is not showing in Metamask wallet

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, nft

Working on ERC1155 standard smart contract

- My smart contract is working fine on Remix, hardhat localhost and mumbai testnet.
- It mints and list the tokens
- User can buy tokens
- Owner balance is also increased in blockchain
- Token amount is transferred to seller.

The only issue I am facing is bought token is not appearing in wallet.
I have tested with all networks but token did not appear.

I tried to manually add it but that also didn't work.

Is there something that I am missing.

I have minted token with `_mint()` function and transferred the token when user purchase it using `safeTrasferFrom()` function

Everything is working fine except token does not appear in wallet.

Answer (score 0):

Which wallet are you using?

If it's Metamask, then you'll have to wait. As per [this](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360058488651-Does-MetaMask-support-ERC-1155-) article, though you may be able to add the ERC1155 tokens in your Metamask wallet, you won't be able to see the balance as well as transfer, as of now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).